# myFunction is not defined with ActiveAdmin form & Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

I don't understand why I have this issue. It's like my function hiddenField() is not read.

My form :

```
f.input :contact, :as => :radio, :collection => ["slide", "formulaire de contact", "map", "video"], input_html: {:class => "select", :onblur => "hiddenField()"}
f.input :title_map, label: I18n.t('title_map'), input_html: {:class => "hidden_title"}, placeholder: "Entrer un titre pour la map"
```

My Script :

```
var ready;
ready = function() {

    function hiddenField() {
        $(".select").on( 'click', function() {
            document.getElementsByClassName("hidden_title").removeAttribute("input");
        };
    };

    hiddenField();
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Thanks.

EDIT :

Sorry, I forgot. My form is in admin/page.rb. I use ActiveAdmin.

Comment: Because you've defined the function inside another function, it cannot be accessed from outside

Comment: Take the function `hiddenField` outside of `ready()` or simply add `window.hiddenField = hiddenField` at the end of `ready()`

Comment: I have the same issue outside...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('.select').change(function() {
    $('.hidden_title').removeAttr('input')
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you add some context on how this solves the OP's question?

Comment: You're right @ilan. onblur event is useless. And my code is a bit messy but it's ok now. I found it needs to add `config.register_javascript 'myFunction.js'` in config/initializers/active_admin.rb for this code works. Thanks.